# Unable to create Bitmap from disk file on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm referencing `CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2` as well as `runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` from a .NET Core project and doing the following:

```
Bitmap frame = new Bitmap($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}\\images\\image_0.bmp")
```

I've checked that the path is correct at runtime. On Windows this works fine, but on Debian I am getting:

```
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0600
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0601
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0602
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0603
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x06dd
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x070f
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2028
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2029
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfff9
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffa
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffb

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus(Status status)
at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename, Boolean useIcm)
at TestVideoConvert.TestVideoConvert.Create() in /home/osboxes/Downloads/Test2/TestVideoConvert/TestVideoConvert.cs:line 44
at ImageResizeNetCore.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/osboxes/Downloads/Test2/ImageResizeNetCore/Program.cs:line 15
```

I've installed `libgdiplus`, but no luck.

Using `System.Drawing.Common` gives the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename, Boolean useIcm)
at TestVideoConvert.TestVideoConvert.Create() in /home/osboxes/Downloads/Test2/TestVideoConvert/TestVideoConvert.cs:line 44
at ImageResizeNetCore.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/osboxes/Downloads/Test2/ImageResizeNetCore/Program.cs:line 15
```

I've read somewhere that this could be due to the image size being too large, but in my case it's a 1920x1080 bmp so not out of the ordinary.

Comment: Did you also reference runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing package?

Comment: @Evk: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I've updated the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **correct path separator** for the current environment.

In your case, you're attempting to concatenate a path using the Windows separator (backslash).  However, Linux uses a forward-slash as its path separator.

So on Windows, your path looks like this: ..\images\image_0.bmp

But on Linux, your path would actually be this: ../images/image_0.bmp

In order to get your code working in all supported environments, use the Path.DirectorySeparatorChar value as your delimiter.

In that case, your code becomes the following:

```
var delim = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
Bitmap frame = new Bitmap($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}{delim}images{delim}image_0.bmp");
```

Comment: D'oh! I'm such an idiot. I actually switched to using ImageSharp to process the bitmaps and it was throwing path not found. I wish System.Drawing actually gave a meaningful error...